# Using Object key as a variable to replace text in file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following code that is supposed to call an api using the object key value and then open a text file and replace the text that matches the key with the API data. To simplify I've removed the API to just loop through they obj keys and then attempt to replace.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const storage  = require('./db/storage')


const keys =  Object.keys(storage.MOVIES);

for (const key of keys) {
    fs.readFile('./db/movies_prebuilt.txt', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
        if (err) {
          return console.log(err);
        }
        //THIS LINE DOESNT WORK using key. but does work using an actual 
        string.
        var result = data.replace(key, "NOTWORKING");
        fs.writeFile('./movies.md', result, 'utf8', function (err) {
           if (err) return console.log(err);
        });
      });
    }
```

The db/storage snippet looks like this:

```
exports.MOVIES = {
    "Matrix_Score": "tt0133093",
    "2001_Space_Score": "tt0062622"
     ...
}
```

And The replacement text inside looks like this

```
 ### Matrix_Score
```

And I have changed the for loop to `data.replace("Matrix_Score","WORKING");` and that works perfectly fine. Is it not possible to use the key as a string? The only reason I want to use it, is so I dont have to write another array or object with all the names, when I have it already.

cheers!

Comment: The line var result = data.replace(key, "WORKING"); doesn't replace the text with what the key is.

Comment: Did you verify that `keys` actually contains the values you expect?

Comment: Yes, I've printed them and have all the keys when looped through.

Comment: *"Is it not possible to use the key as a string?"* `key` is a variable that holds a string value. A string value is always a string.

Comment: What is the result for the `Matrix_Score` key if you do `console.log(key, key === "Matrix_Score");`. What if you do `console.log(key, key.length)` ?

Comment: Matrix_Score true which was a test previously I had attempted oddly Catalyst method worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this following code may be closer to what I am understanding the intention is. `fs.readFile` returns all of the file contents, and you likely want to replace *all* of the keys, not just the last one. Also no need to read the file multiple times:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const storage  = require('./db/storage')

const keys =  Object.keys(storage.MOVIES);

fs.readFile('./db/movies_prebuilt.txt', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  for (const key of keys) {
    data = data.toString().replace(key, "NOTWORKING");
  }
  fs.writeFile('./movies.md', data, 'utf8', function (err) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
  });
});
```

EDIT to add back the original point

`fs.readFile` typically returns a Buffer which needs to be `.toString`'d to be manipulated.

Comment: That doesn't explain why it would work if the are using a string literal.

Comment: yeah I mis-read and jumped to the first problem I saw. I will update with more suggestions.

Comment: That fixes the issue. I should of known better :)

Comment: Isn't the buffer returned only if no encoding is specified, and a string otherwise? But OP did specify an encoding, UTF-8. [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback)

Comment: @JamesPerkins .toString() fixes it? That's wholly unexpected after CertainPerformance's point which should be right

Comment: Yup, I throw a data.toString().replace(key,"WORKING") and it worked exactly as expected.

Comment: Great, @JamesPerkins I also added updates with other suggestions that may make it run faster

Comment: Thanks @Catalyst I had moved the for loop for testing so your suggestions are perfect thansk so much